How much data in S3 will be backup for the first time?
Let say I have a S3 bucket which I created it and uploaded files to it a year ago. I kept it unchanged for a year. Now I turn on backup on it using continuous backup and set the total retention period to be 35 days (which is the max. value).
Will my files that were uploaded a year ago able to be backup? I just have a doubt whether the initial backup taken will include a full backup from the S3 bucket regardless how old those files are.

The initial backup will do a full backup of your S3 bucket. It's point-in-time backup, so it makes a backup of your bucket as it was at a specific time, not based on when the objects in the bucket were created.
More details can be seen in the documentation, but important piece is "The first backup of a bucket is a full backup". This is true for both periodic and continuous backups.

Thanks Caldazar.
If so, when the backup starts to happen daily and I restore the backup let say to the most recent time, will the restore contain the the files which were created in the source bucket a year ago?
Still a bit confused how the 35 days retention affect the whole backup and restore process

That depends on whether you have deleted those files and when. If you deleted them before the restore point they will not be visible, but if you deleted them after the restore point, they will be visible. With continuous backup, you can restore to any point in time in the last 35 days.
